# Ruby Yield in Rails Controllers variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

I am trying to understand the following method of a rails controller

```
def self.collect_with_max_id(collection=[], max_id=nil, &block)
        response = yield(max_id)
        collection += response
        response.empty? ? collection.flatten : collect_with_max_id(collection, response.last.id - 1, &block)
    end
```

When trying to debug the method with byebug I get values for all the objects collection and max_id:
I am stuck on this part

```
response = yield(max_id)
```

while there is a max_id of 552860227390144512, when calling the response variable I simply get an empty array [] and it seems to break the whole method.

Could someone explanin the yield function in this context. I only now it from rendering views and blocks in ror.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` is a keyword in ruby and it is used to execute the block given to the method.

```
def foo
  yield 'Hi 1'
  yield 'Hi 2'
end

foo { |string| puts string }

# Hi 1
# Hi 2
```

In your case the block is also taken in a variable `&block` so you can do a recursion:

```
def bar(i = 1,  &block)
  return if i <= 0

  yield(i) # or you can do block.call(i)

  bar(i - 1, &block)
end

bar(3) { |i| puts "I am called with #{i}" }
```

The method stops the recursion because of the last line. You ask whether the `response.empty?` and if it is you'll return `collection.flatten`

The tl&dr is forget about rails for couple of months and learn the ruby language otherwise you'll be in a world of hurt.